# Function not returning (Clojure)

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.logic

I am new to clojure, my function elligble voters is not returning the vector, where am i going wrong.

```
(def human-db
  [
   {:name "Kanishk" :age 28 :sex "male"}
   {:name "Kanishk1" :age 29 :sex "male"}
   {:name "Kanishk2" :age 0 :sex "female"}
   {:name "Kanishk3" :age 1 :sex "male"}
   {:name "Kanishk4" :age 3 :sex "female"}
   {:name "Kanishk5" :age 3 :sex "male"}
   {:name "Kanishk6" :age 3 :sex "female"}
   {:name "Kanishk7" :age 3 :sex "male"}
   {:name "Kanishk8" :age 3 :sex "female"}])


(defn elligble-voters
  [human-db]
  (reduce (fn
            [new-map map]
            (if (> (:age map) 18)
              (conj new-map map)))  [] human-db))
(elligble-voters human-db)
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: you have no second branch of `if`: if age is less than or equals 18 it just returns nil . you need to return the accumulator (`new-map`) instead: `(if ... (conj ...) new-map)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your `if` expression - there is no else clause, so it is returning nil when the voter is aged less than 18.

The last item in `human-db` is aged 3, so the `if` returns `nil`, and thus reduce returns `nil`.

This works:

```clj
(defn elligble-voters [human-db]
  (reduce (fn [new-map map]
            (if (> (:age map) 18)
              (conj new-map map)
              new-map)) ;; <-- Added `new-map` here
          []
          human-db))
```

A neater way to express the same function would be like this:

```
(filter (fn [{:keys [age]}] (> age 18)) human-db)
```

Answer (score 0):

while `reduce` if capable of doing what you want, use something more suited for filtering a collection.

i.e. `filter`

> clojure.core/filter
>   ([pred] [pred coll])
>
> Returns a lazy sequence of the items in coll for which
>     (pred item) returns logical true. pred must be free of side-effects.
>     Returns a transducer when no collection is provided.

---

```
(defn elligble-voters [human-db]
  (filter #(> (:age %) 18) human-db))
```

`#(> (:age %) 18)` is an shorthand for an anonymous function, equivalent to

```
(fn [x] 
  (> (:age x) 18))
```